# Ribbon on Picture library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

I have a picture library and in this page, I added a Media Content (Content Editor) web part but for some reason on this library I dont see the ribbon up top to save. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js Jump "></script>


<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(document).ready(function(){

var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");


           if(elem != null) {


                var dummyevent = new Array();


                dummyevent["target"] = elem;


                dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;


                WpClick(dummyevent);


                _ribbonStartInit("Ribbon.Browse", true)


            }


 });


</script>
```

This "bug" happens with pages with content editors, so you have to apply this in order to get the ribbon back.

Comment: I paste this on the content editor web part space but I cant save because there is no ribbon. How do make the webpart keep this change

Comment: I was finally able to paste it and save it just by jumping to another place of my SharePoint but still no ribbon, now I have a content editor web part that shows this info you told me to paste. But no ribbon

Comment: this will give you more details on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848892/list-tools-tab-is-no-longer-available-after-adding-webpart-to-the-page

Comment: I did miss one step on the how to, sorry!